# Running on iphone through xCode debugger works, but crashes on iPhone on startup

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

Firstly, if any code is needed, do comment and tell me and I will provide you with it. I will provide my appDelegate.swift below since it's called on startup.

So my issue starts out like this. I used the prototype app on my iphone for a day yesterday. Tested it, no issues. This morning when I tried to on the app, (i restarted my phone in the morning too, it's a habit of mine) it shows the launchscreen but crashes immediately afterwards. Odd thing is, when I connected the phone immediately after the crash to xcode to try and debug it, it works. Any idea what the issue is?

Thanks in advance!

My appDelegate.swift:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import AVFoundation

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient)

    // passing managedObjectContext:

    let todayViewController = window!.rootViewController as! TodayViewController

    todayViewController.managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext

    return true

}

func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification) {
    print("Did receive Local Notification: \(notification)")
}

func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
    self.saveContext()
}

// MARK: - Core Data stack

lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSURL = {
    // The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file. This code uses a directory named "RaymondMoay.Streak" in the application's documents Application Support directory.
    let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
    return urls[urls.count-1]
}()

lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
    // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
    let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Streak", withExtension: "momd")!
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)!
}()

lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {
    // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and returns a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
    // Create the coordinator and store
    let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
    let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("SingleViewCoreData.sqlite")
    print(url)
    var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
    do {
        try coordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: [NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: true, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: true])
    } catch {
        // Report any error we got.
        var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason

        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error as NSError
        let wrappedError = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
        // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(wrappedError), \(wrappedError.userInfo)")
        abort()
    }

    return coordinator
}()

lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
    let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
    return managedObjectContext
}()

// MARK: - Core Data Saving support

func saveContext () {
    if managedObjectContext.hasChanges {
        do {
            try managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nserror = error as NSError
            NSLog("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Any error message? Does it show the linenumber where it fails? Easy way to identify the issue is to test part-for-part what causes the crash. Use the /* and */ markers to comments out each part.

Comment: When you ran in Xcode, did you reset the simulator first, corresponding to restarting your phone?

Comment: @Robski18 it failed when it wasn't connected to xcode's debugger, so I couldn't find the code that causes the crash. And when I did connect it to the debugger, there is no more crash.

Comment: @Feldur Yes I did that, however there was no crash. Could this be an internal issue with xcode itself? I'm afraid when it's deployed to the app store it might happen to a customer. It'll be pretty frustrating to redownload the app.

Comment: You can get the crash log and the iPhone's console log by using the Xcode device window.

Comment: @Philip Mills is right. You also could download [iOS Console](http://lemonjar.com/iosconsole/), plug that in and see what the phone has to say. I'd say the odds it's Xcode aren't good.

Comment: Oh alright I get it, I'll try it every time I start the app as I somehow can't seem to reproduce the bug. Thanks for helping, will be updating the issue. Thanks guys!